# How to elegantly beautify a topojson code?

Tags: topojson

**Is there some tool to explore the tree structure of the one-line topojson files ?** (beautify)

```
{"type":"Topology","transform":{"scale":[0.0015484881821515486,0.0010301030103010299],"translate":-5.491666666666662,41.008333333333354]},"objects": {"level_0001m":{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[0]],"properties":{"name":1}},{"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[1]],"properties":{"name":1}},{ ... }]},"level_0050m":{ ... }}}
```

---

**Comments:** My current method is to open the topojson .json into a text editor, and to manually look for clues while browsing. I end up sumarizing the whole by hand and keeping an handy note, something like :

```
{
"type":"Topology",
"transform": 
    {
    "scale": [0.0015484881821515486,0.0010301030103010299],
    "translate":[-5.491666666666662,41.008333333333354]
    },
"objects": {
    "level_0001m":
        {
        "type":"GeometryCollection",
        "geometries": 
            [
            {"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[0]],"properties":{"name":1}},
            {"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[1]],"properties":{"name":1}},
            { ... }
            ]
        },
    "level_0050m":
        { ... }
    }
}
```

But is there some more advanced tools to open, explore, edit topojson ?

Comment: I guess any tool to explore JSON should do.

Comment: It seems however that most beautifiers either crash with big files either make an **overeach beautification** by adding line jump to each single `;` `,` `{` `}` `[` `]` etc.

Comment: Issue opened at: https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/issues/108

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a JSON prettifier, example: http://pro.jsonlint.com

Use http://jsoneditoronline.org 
[image]

Comment: Beautify **too much**, doesn't really help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/). I just did it this way.

Comment: Crash quite quickly with [heavier files](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4090846/world-50m.json)

Comment: I've no better idea, though my file is much heavier than yours.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with Windows try [JSONedit](http://tomeko.net/software/JSONedit/). It's generic JSON editor, but it is relatively efficient when handling medium size JSON files (like your world-50m.json: 747 kB, 254k nodes including 165k int and 88k array nodes). Similar files to your notes can be created by deleting array elements after few initial ones (RMB + "Delete all siblings after node").

Answer (score 1):

http://jsonprettyprint.com/json-pretty-printer.php
I tried this one with a file of 1.9 mb and it worked, maybe it'll work for you aswell

Answer (score 1):

js-beautify from the command line generates json the way I would write them by hand.

https://github.com/einars/js-beautify